# Proving global minima of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization, logarithms, maxima-minima

I have the following function:
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-\log(x^2y^2\sin^2z)$$
Dealing with the case where $x>0,y>0,z\in(-\pi,\pi]$, I have shown that it has stationary points at $(1,1,-\pi/2)$ and $(1,1,\pi/2)$. Using the Hessian, I've shown that they are local minima. I've shown that the function goes to positive infinity when $x$ or $y$ go to zero or infinity, and when $z$ goes to zero, $-\pi$, or $\pi$. How can I show that these minima are global minima in this region? Is there a general theorem I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x,y,z)\geq \sum_{cyc}(x^2-2\ln{x})\geq2.$$

Indeed, let $g(x)=x^2-2\ln{x}.$

Thus, $$g'(x)=2x-\frac{2}{x}=\frac{2(x-1)(x+1)}{x},$$ which gives $x_{min}=1$ and
$$g(x)\geq g(1)=1.$$

The equality occurs for $(x,y,z)=\left(1,1,\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$ which says that $2$ is a minimal value of $f$.

Comment: Would this be equivalent to saying:
$$f(x,y,z)=(x^2-2\log(x))+(y^2-2\log(y))-\log(\sin^2z)$$
and that the function is minimized at these values of each component?

I.e. $x^2-2\log(x)$ is minimized at $x=1$, same for $y$, and $-\log(\sin^2z)$ is minimized at $\pm\frac\pi 2$

Comment: You need to find a minimal value and I found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the special case of Weierstrass [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

Even if the domain is not compact, since the function is continuos and tends to $+\infty$ at the boundary, it must reach a minimum value in the domain.

Comment: Do you have a source for that version of the theorem? I'm looking for one which doesn't require compactness, but I haven't found it.

Comment: I can't find now, anyway you could simply consider a restriction on a compact such that $$f(x,y,z)\le M$$ which exists by IVT and then apply EVT.

Comment: Don't you need that the points are global minima to prove they are in any such set?

Comment: You have found a minimum $m$ at $P_m$, now the idea is to consider a compact domain which contains $P_m$ such that $m\le f(x,y,z) \le M$. For EVT in this compact restriction $m$ is a global minimum. Since $f(x)\ge M>m$ in the complement open set, thus $m$ is a global minimum also in the original domain.